# Js calling iframe XX seconds after playing a video

Tags: javascript, php

I'm setting up a javascript that after playing a video, pops up an iframe which appears 11 seconds after the play button is clicked.

My code is apparently correct, but for some reasons isn't working at all.

```
function myiframe() { 
    setTimeout(function(){ video.play(), 11000); } 
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("popupstyle").style.display="inline";
    var video=document.getElementById("myvid");
    var playButton=document.getElementById("play-pause");
    playButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
        if(video.paused==true){
            video.play();
            playButton.innerHTML="&nbsp;";
        } else {
            video.pause();
            playButton.innerHTML="&nbsp;";
        }
    });
}

<div class="controls"><button type="button" id="play-pause" class="play"><img src="img/play.png"></button></div>
<iframe id="popup" class="whiterussian" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" src="pages/myframe.php"></iframe>
<div id="popupstyle"></div>
```

Comment: Your `setTimeout` syntax is wrong (`;` then `,`, the callback function is not closed at the right place). Please use the inbuilt StackOverflow editor to post such samples, you can format it automatically this way and detect such errors more easily.

Comment: @Triby You [altered the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59470499/revisions) while formatting the code in the post.

Comment: Just took out that ; and added the end bracket.

Comment: @Triby You shouldn't modify the syntax at all when doing an edit.

Comment: the question suggests you want to display a popup after clicking play but the timed function only attempts to play a video and not open a popup?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but even now with the syntax corrected the vid is not playing at all on click. Have I forgotten something in the code?

Comment: please clarify your intention with the `setTimeout` ~ it tries to play the video which should,according to your question, have been playing already for 11s

Comment: My code is intended to place a play button which will, when clicked, play a vid and also at the same time shows a popup which will be displayed 11 seconds after the video starts

Comment: The edit made to the question obscures the original intent. It appears that the `myiframe` function ONLY tries to play the video. Are you suggesting that ALL of the javascript belongs inside that function body?

Comment: I was successfully using this code to show popup 13s after visitors joined the page, regardless of watching the vid or not: window.onload=function() {
setTimeout('document.getElementById("popup").style.display="block"',13000);
setTimeout('document.getElementById("popupstyle").style.display="inline"',13000);
var video=document.getElementById("myvid");
var playButton=document.getElementById("play-pause");
playButton.addEventListener("click",function(){if(video.paused==true){video.play();
playButton.innerHTML="&nbsp;";}else{video.pause();
playButton.innerHTML="&nbsp;";}});}

Comment: ... Now I just wanna change it and make it show up just 11 seconds after the play video button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is the intention? There was no video element in the question so I added one here to test - the button plays the video OK and then displays the iframe and div after 11s.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>popups and videos</title>
        <style>
            #popup{display:none;}
            #popupstyle{display:none;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <video width=400 height=300 id='myvid' autoplay=false controls=true loop=true src='/images/video/bubbles_xtrails.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>

        <div class='controls'>
            <button type='button' id='play-pause' class='play'>
                <img src='img/play.png'>
            </button>
        </div>

        <iframe id='popup' class='whiterussian' scrolling='no' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' frameborder='0' src='pages/myframe.php'></iframe>
        <div id='popupstyle'></div>

        <script>
            document.getElementById('play-pause').addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
                e.target.innerHTML='&nbsp';
                var video=document.getElementById('myvid');

                setTimeout( ()=>{
                    document.getElementById('popup').style.display='block';
                    document.getElementById('popupstyle').style.display='inline';
                }, 11000 );

                if( video.paused==true ){
                    video.play();
                }else{
                    video.pause();
                }   
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great work, you even added much stuff to create a complete code.
By the way it still doesn't work. How about we simply work on this part? [code]playButton.addEventListener("click",function(){if(video.paused==true){video.play();[/code]
This code is calling the 'function', successfully. Function is tho defined this way: [code] window.onload=function() {[/code] Can we change window.onload=function() into video.play=function() or something? I think that would be much simpler than writing new codes...

Comment: `Can we change window.onload=function() into video.play=function() or something?` - please explain as I don't understand what you mean here. BTW - this works for me-it plays the video and after 11s displays the two elements

Comment: The main problem is I'm using a custom player (which I didn't create myself but just reproduced), while you typed me something using a basic html5 player which is not what I need graphically. With my bad knowledge I have then tried to take pieces of your code and make it work into mine, but it does not work (I probably make something wrong in my conversion, obv). So that's why I gave up with this and retried using my original code (as shown in my recent question). I sincerely appreciate your efforts, you even built a complete code, but unfortunately it resulted in more confusion for me :-/

Comment: OK - but your "custom player" accepts `play()` and `pause()` methods so the actual HTML video element ( HTML5 or custom ) is irrelevant. It is surely just the functionality you require : ie, click the button, the video starts and then Xseconds later the iFrame is made visible?

Comment: Yup, I think one user has recently found out the issue which is supposed to be this. And ironically he doesn't either have the knowledge to edit my original code properly... "You've got the playButton.addEventListener nested inside the window.onclick, could be that's what's causing the two-click requirement.

And the setTimeout is inside window.click but not inside playButton.addEventListener("click"..., meaning clicking the button will not fire it, but clicking the window will, (after 27 seconds)."

Comment: The guy in the end solved my question. Thanks for all your efforts guys I appreciate^^